# What happens when one uses a blender in zero gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

I was recently told by a friend that using a blender type apparatus in a zero gravity environment will act like a centrifuge instead mixing properly. Is this the case? Furthermore, can anyone provide a proper citation for this?

I have tried to find papers/articles through Google (and Google Scholar), but can't seem to find any information about the effects of blending in zero gravity.

Comment: I haven't done any scholarly searches on it, but it makes sense.  When I visualize the operation in my head, a blender uses a centrifuge like effect to fling matter outward, and up the sides.  It then relies on gravity to pull material down the central axis back into the blender.   Without gravity for the second half, it at least seems reasonable that what you are left with is a centrifuge.

Comment: Your friend has the right intuition. A conventional blender is very sensitive to material sticking to the walls due to the motion. One does not need to be in space to have experience with this. Blenders with cylindrical cross section perform very poorly, even on Earth, because most of the material simply moves to the wall without coming into contact with the blades much. It takes a square vessel to prevent this from happening. A blender that is useful in space will need, at least, two counter-rotating blades.

Comment: You could try running the blender sideways to see what happens. Not the same as 0 gravity, but at least the gravity would be acting in another direction.

Comment: @user854 Better to try upside-down mode with blender full of products. In this case gravity will not push contents towards the blades at all, which will be similar to zero gravity conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you envision the rotating blender to be in outer space will be the same as removing the downward gravity on it. For a blender to operate properly, gravity is needed to pull all the stuff inside towards the blending blades. Only stuff at the bottom will be blended. Not too well though because it ends up at the wall of the container (out of reach of the blades) after the blades are set in motion. The blended stuff below can set the rest of the stuff inside in motion too (by touching). So you'll end up with a small fraction of improperly blended stuff and a majority of non-blended stuff which will find a way out of the container eventually because it gets also a motion parallel to the walls of the container. It's kind of a centrifuge because if water were present, this would finally be thrown out of the container. But also the stuff to be centrifuged would be thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one you would have a problem with the craft you are in staying still. They are most likely correct though it would probably act like a centrifuge because there is nothing to pull the reactant down off the wall.

Comment: Heh.  "Oh no, we're spinning off course!  Oh, Fred's making a milkshake."

Comment: @AskAboutMonica You ain't seen nothing yet. Fred has yet to open the blender to get the milkshake out when he's done.